# Web site design issue

Tags: html, css

i am kind of new to designing stuff which is why i want to learn a bit about it..
I am having an issue with my website, what css can I use to make a Div acting as a wraper grow in terms of height as the content grows? My content is being hidden underneath the footer... as it grows

Thank you

css

```
    .wrapper
{
    width :1200px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow :hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Having your code posted somewhere would be helpful.

Comment: Please give us more details. What will happen if the height grows more than usual. Do you looking for a solution to avoid Scrolling? Do you want to consider an special space for each content? Please enrich your question with the current codes.

Comment: i added the css for the wrapper - the issue is that i have it as hidden but i am not sure what to add there to make it grow...(the div that is.. as the content grows)

Comment: if you want to comment please put it inside comment section and not in the answer section.

Comment: No i just want the div to grow in height if the content overflows.. no scrolling within the wrapper is preferred.. just not sure what else to add to the wrapper css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
.wrapper
{
width :1200px;
height: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow :hidden;
background-color: white;
}
```

to this:

Change this:

```
.wrapper
{
width :1200px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not entirely clear, but you could use `min-height` to make an element have a minimum height:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1200px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uQjEn/3/

And:

http://jsfiddle.net/uQjEn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever use overflow: hidden with an explicit height. I know all the cool kids are using that to contain floats but you can't combine that with a height set.

Remove the overflow property or the height property.